# Using IF function instead concatenate to get clear results

Tags: excel

I want to combine 5 cells (Item Type    Specification   Brand   Part Number Description)  as result

```
 ITEM, TYPE (SPECIFICATION) (BRAND PART)
```

I am using concatenate formula as

```
=CONCATENATE(A2,", ",B2," (",C2,") (",D2," ",E2,")")
```

but issue is by default view is

```
",  () ( )"
```

Now if specification is blank result will be "a, a () (s s)".

I don't want these brackets if specification is blank or brand part is blank.
Can any one please let me know IF function so that I can see clear results.

Many thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ravinder

Answer (score 0):

Like so?

[image]

Formula in `F3` and downwards:

```
=A3&", "&B3&IF(C3<>""," ("&C3&")","")&IF(OR(D3<>"",E3<>"")," ("&D3&IF(AND(D3<>"",E3<>"")," ","")&E3&")","")
```

Comment: Hi Axel, Please let me know if you can help me to understand IF and related logic to use in excel.. I am quite dumb in this

Comment: The logic of the `IF` function in Excel is explained here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2. `AND`function see here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9. `OR` function: https://support.office.com/en-US/article/OR-function-7D17AD14-8700-4281-B308-00B131E22AF0. `CONCATENATE` function but also hint the `&`as concatenation operator: https://support.office.com/en-US/article/CONCATENATE-function-8F8AE884-2CA8-4F7A-B093-75D702BEA31D.

Answer (score 0):

```
=CONCATENATE(A3,", ",B3,IF(ISBLANK(C3),CONCATENATE(""),CONCATENATE(" (",C3,")")), " (",D3," ",E3,")")
```

Use combination of concatenate, if and is blank. I have done it for specification, use same for BRAND.
All the best. :)

Comment: Thank you Nitin.. But issue will be still there as I don't want () if any of fields are blank.. but solution given by Axel Richter perfectly meet my requirement .. but thanks to you also...